# How to Use form1 datagridview1 (all rows) into form2 datagridview2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have two form(`form1`,`form2`). In `form1` having `datagridview1` and `form2` having `datagridview2`. I want click a button, all data are from `form1_datagridview1` to display in `form2_datagridview2`.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `DataGridView2` as `public` and write following code in `Botton_Click` of `Form1`:

```
var frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.dataGridview2.DataSoure = this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
frm2.Show();
```

Comment: @bala: In your form, right click on datagridview, and from property panel set it's `Modifiers` property to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

use this on Form1 button Click

```
var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault();
if (form != null)
{
  Form tempChild = form;
  DataGridView dd = (DataGridView)tempChild.Controls["datagridview2 of form2"];
  dd.DataSoure = this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
}
```